# What does 'ls -la' do?

Tags: command-line, ls

When I entered the `-al` attribute with the [ls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls) command, I got the following:

```
anupam@JAZZ:~/blog$ ls -al
total 76
drwxrwxr-x 13 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 21:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 34 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 20:52 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 12:19 app
drwxr-xr-x  2 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 12:19 bin
drwxrwxr-x  5 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 12:19 config
-rw-rw-r--  1 anupam anupam  154 Aug 28 12:19 config.ru
drwxrwxr-x  3 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 12:37 db
-rw-rw-r--  1 anupam anupam 1339 Aug 28 12:19 Gemfile
-rw-rw-r--  1 anupam anupam 2871 Aug 28 12:19 Gemfile.lock
drwxrwxr-x  7 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 21:45 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 anupam anupam  466 Aug 28 12:19 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  4 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 12:19 lib
drwxrwxr-x  2 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 12:29 log
drwxrwxr-x  2 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 12:19 public
-rw-rw-r--  1 anupam anupam  249 Aug 28 12:19 Rakefile
-rw-rw-r--  1 anupam anupam  478 Aug 28 12:19 README.rdoc
drwxrwxr-x  8 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 12:19 test
drwxrwxr-x  6 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 12:33 tmp
drwxrwxr-x  3 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 12:19 vendor
```

What does each column mean, and what does the `total 76` signify here?

Comment: For similar questions in the future, this online tool is pretty awesome. http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ls+-al

Comment: @dan08 That explains the command, but not the output.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `ls -al` command is a combination of `ls -l` (use a long listing format) and `ls -a` (do not ignore entries starting with .)

The result is a *long list* (the `ls -l` part) with (from left to right):

- filetype
- file permissions
- number of links
- owner name
- owner group
- file size
- time of last modification
- the name of the file or directory

while the `ls -a` means that hidden files are listed as well.

see also [`man ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ls.1) (as always `man` is the first source of information), and [this link](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/linux-ls-command).

**A little more explanation on what you see**

The output starts with the number of disc blocks, used by the directory (in your case 76). From [the GNU docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#What-information-is-listed):

> For each directory that is listed, preface the files with a line
>   ‘total blocks’, where blocks is the total disk allocation for all
>   files in that directory. The block size currently defaults to 1024
>   bytes, but this can be overridden.

Then:

- the first character describes wether it is a directory (`d`) or a file (`-`) (or some other file type, see [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#What-information-is-listed) for a complete listing)

*File permissions:*

- the permissions in a nine-character section (3x3 for owner / group / other users)

*Links*

- The number of links is the number of hard links to the file. For a directory, the number of hard links is the number of (immediate) subdirectories plus the parent directory and itself.

*Owner*

- name of the owner
- name of the (owner) group

*File size*

- You see many files with the size of `4096`, which is the minimum size for a directory on `ext3` and `ext4`.

Comment: Thanx sir,You gave me a clear understanding of what exactly I was looking for..

Answer (score 4):

ls - list directory contents

You have 76 directories in /home/blog

drwxrwxr-x - These are the permissions for each one

The number after the permissions is the number of file/folders/links in this folder

After that the current user

After that the folders owner

Next is the group ID for the group the file belongs too.

Next is date and time the file was modified

The far right entery is the name of the folder

You can append `ls` with other commands for example

```
ls -a
```

Displays hidden files (starting with .)

[You can find all the commands here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ls.1.html)

Comment: 76 directories in /home or in /home/blog ?

Comment: sorry /home/blog/ I assumed you were just in /home

Comment: Okay sir,then what does ,13 means in [drwxrwxr-x 13 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 21:45 .] and 34 means in[drwxr-xr-x 34 anupam anupam 4096 Aug 28 20:52 ..]

Comment: The 76 does not indicate the number of directories inside the directory which `ls` shows. See this example: http://pastebin.com/S411HeJG There are clearly no directories inside the one shown by `ls`, but it says `8` as total.

Comment: The total number of file links and folders but ls ONLY lists folders

Comment: See [Why does \`ls -l\` count more files than me?](//askubuntu.com/q/810563)