# Default number of links for directory?

Tags: directory, symbolic-link, hard-link, stat

I know that hard link can not point to directories but when i create an empty directory and execute stat command for it

[image]

links=2 ,I search for symbolic links

[image]

There is not another link. why for directory the default numbers of links=2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer:

The number of links to a directory is *at least* two:

- The link to the parent directory
- The link to itself

See also [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/517240/72216):

> The number of links is the number of hard links to the file. For a directory, the number of hard links is the number of (immediate) subdirectories plus the parent directory and itself.