# What does ls -l echo out?

Tags: bash

```
$ ls -l
-rw------- 1 root root 2381 Jan 13 08:20 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  444 Jan 13 08:20 known_hosts
```

- 1st one is permissions
- 2nd one is ?
- 3rd one is ownership
- 4th one is ?
- 5th one is ?
- 6th one is date created
- 7th one is filename

Could someone fill in the gaps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'ls -la' do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/517229/what-does-ls-la-do) - also see [what does terminal command: ls -l show?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578647/what-does-terminal-command-ls-l-show) on Stack Overflow and [What do the fields in ls -al output mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean) on Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pictures explains better than words.**

[image]

**File Type:** `-`: file,  `d`: directory

**Permission:** `r`: read, `w`: write, `x`: executable

*Rest is self explanatory in above picture.*

Answer (score 1):

- 2nd one is number of links
- 4th one is group
- 5th one is filesize
- 6th one one though I would believe is date modified

Some extra info: do a

```
stat {filename}
```

and you get more information about the file.