# Packages and meaning of gcc-8

Tags: apt, package-management, gcc, ls

`ls -la` commands below brings file information gcc-8 that looks strange for me. I suppose it is not link. I know there are different GCC packages with different GCC versions and it looks like I have package with GCC version 8.

How to know gcc-8 is package and not link? Where this package is located? Why other binaries does not show its packages?

```
ls -la /usr/bin/gcc
```

brings

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Apr 22  2021 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-8
```

Comment: Why do you suppose it's not a link? Do you know [what the first column of `ls -l` is for](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517229/what-does-ls-la-do)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to know gcc-8 is package and not link?**

`gcc-8` can refer both to a package and a file or link.
And most likely if you have package `gcc-8`, it will provide a file named `gcc-8` (perhaps more than one).
For instance, check with

```
$ dpkg -l | grep gcc-8
```

That will tell you whether package `gcc-8` is installed in your system (ar use simply `gcc` instead of `gcc-8` for other versions).
Assuming you see package `gcc-8` is present in your system, you can list all files provided by that package with

```
$ dpkg -L gcc-8
```

In the case you describe, `/usr/bin/gcc` is clearly a link to `/usr/bin/gcc-8`.
If you want to know whether `/usr/bin/gcc-8` is a file or link, simply use

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/gcc-8
```

same as you did.

**Where this package is located?**

Packages have no location. They are installed, providing many files across the filesystem.

**Why other binaries does not show its packages?**

If you provide an example, the community might help clarifying this for you.